# C Pointer Arithmetic on Characters

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code that crashes at the line where I am initializing `ch`:

```
    char * p = "Test";
    char ch = *p++;
    printf("Here : %s\n%c", p, ch);
```

However the following code has no problem:

```
    char * p = "Test";
    char ch = *p++;
    ch++;
    printf("Here : %s\n%c", p, ch);
```

Comment: `char p_data[] = "Test", *p = p_data;` gives you your own copy of the string data, allowing you to modify it.

Comment: Maybe the edit on line 2 of the first segment should be reversed.  It makes reading this question confusing.  For anyone else, the second line in the first segment was originally "char ch = (*p)++;".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first situation, you're trying to change the `T` in the "Test" string compiled into the program, which is held in a part of memory that your code isn't meant to change (usually; there are some environments where it's allowed, but usually it isn't). That's because `(*p)++` means *(loosely speaking)* `*p = *p + 1` (e.g., get the character pointed to by `p`, increment it, and write it back), and of course, `*p` is pointing to the compiled-in "Test".

Your second version doesn't have that problem, because you're incrementing `ch`, which you *are* allowed to change. Your second version actually increments two different things, in fact; first it does `char ch = *p++;` which retrieves the character at `*p` and then increments `p` (now it points to the "e" in "Test"), and then you do `ch = ch++`. (You probably meant just `ch++;` there, since `++` operates directly on its operand.)

Comment: But if I don't write const char * p, then why am I not allowed to change the string via p?

Comment: @Swaranga: Because of the way C is defined and the way programs are loaded into memory. Operating systems categorize memory into *segments*, which can be "code" or "data" (or a couple of others I won't go into). You're trying to change data stored in a code segment, which results in an access violation -- 99.999999% of the time, it's inappropriate for a program to modify a code segment. Your second example *copies* the character from the code segment into an area (the stack) where you're allowed to modify it.

Comment: @Swaranga Sarma: Because the thing that makes the string "Test" read only is not the compiler but the linker.  It's the linker that marks the text segment (i.e. the program + constant string data) as read only and it is the operating system that enforces the read only status.

Comment: And I should have said (and now have) that this isn't *universally* true. There are environments where you're allowed to modify that data directly. But they're typically embedded systems and such.

Comment: It's not necessarily in the code segment, but modifying the array backing a string literal is undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour could be an access violation, a system crash, working correctly, or outputting a proof of P=NP.

Comment: @aaz: Yeah, I think it might be the BSS (depending on implementation). In any case, it's something he shouldn't be changing (usually).

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes down to operator precedence and use of parentheses `()`.

```
char ch = (*p)++;
```

This line will (attempt to) increment the character at the address stored in `p`

```
char ch = *p++;
```

This one sets `ch` equal to the character at the address stored in `p`, then increments the address stored in `p`. The `++` operator takes precedence over the pointer dereference operator, so it will be executed first. To be clear, the second line is equivalent to:

```
char ch = *(p++);
```

Comment: Or, in other words, the second line is equal to `*(p++)`

Comment: @Swaranga Sarma: `(*p)++` means "add one to the *character* at address p", whereas `ch++` means add one to the *address* ch.

Comment: @averell: Good call. I added that to my answer.

Comment: @Swaranga: Because you're allowed to change `ch`; you *aren't* allowed to change `*p`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: That is a good point. There are two things going on here. One: incorrect use of pointer dereferencing, and two: the attempt to modify a const char

Answer (score 1):

Your first example increments the value at `*p`. Since p points to a string constant, this is not allowed with many compilers.

Your second example increments the pointer, not the value it points to.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

`(*p)++`

is trying to increment the value that p points to. p is pointing to the const char string "Test", which cannot be modified.

Comment: char * p is not declared as const

Comment: It can't be modified *in his particular compiler, on his particular OS*.  Some compiler/platform combos will allow it.

Comment: @Swaranga - p is not declared as const, but p refers to a string literal "Test", which is in a read-only memory page.

Answer (score 0):

The first version is doing this:

```
char * p = "Test";  //this should really be const char *
*p = *p + 1;  //CRASH! attempthing to modifiy the contents of a string literal
char ch = *p;
ch = ch++;  //This is excessive, ch++ on it's own would do the same
printf("Here : %s\n%c", p, ch);
```

While the second version is doing this:

```
char * p = "Test"; //still should be const char *
char ch = *p;
p++; //p now points to "est"
ch = ch++;
printf("Here : %s\n%c", p, ch);  //prints est\nU
```